# Use Ajax and Confirm message for delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get a confirm message on clicking delete ImageButton. If the user selects 'Ok' then delete is done, else if 'Cancel' is clicked nothing happens.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/forDesign/delete.png"   OnClientClick="ConfirmDelete()"  />

<script type="text/JavaScript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (x)
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "SearchTicket.aspx/Delete",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });           
    }
```

and in code behind I have:

```
 [WebMethod]
public void Delete()
{
    string code = DetailsViewCodeTicket.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    Ticket.TicketCusDelete(code);
    DetailsViewCodeTicket.DataBind();
}
```

but when I clicking the ImageButton I get this error:

[image]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should launch your lightbox on click first.... and then, when the user confirm you trigger your ajax call...

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/976oxwmk/

```
<button>remove</button>
```

js

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    var confirmation = confirm("are you sure you want to remove the item?");

    if (confirmation) {
     // execute ajax
        alert('removed');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add curly brackets:

```
if(x){
ajax code ....
}
```

so this will be the overall code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/forDesign/delete.png"   OnClientClick="ConfirmDelete()"  />
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (x) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "SearchTicket.aspx/Delete",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing an answer for the original poster's question. Please be mindful of formatting the answer appropriately. For further help, see the following markdown guide: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help